# Forward pfsenselogs to graylog

Tags: pfsense, graylog

I was wondering if it is possible to forward pfsense logs (including snort) to a graylog2 server? And how can this be acomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pfSense supports standard syslog, so as long as greylog2 supports syslog, then you're all set. If it doesn't, then you can use logstash as a conduit between syslog and greylog2.

Comment: Thanks. Wel Graylog2 does support syslog. But i am just not sure how i can modify Pfsense to forward the logs?

Comment: You don't have to modify pfSense at all - it already has syslog support. Status->System Logs->Settings->Remote Logging Options.

Comment: There are extractors for pfsense for graylog: https://nmanzi.com/graylog-extractors-for-pfsense-2-2-filter-logs/

Comment: Any way to show "most visited" sites?